# Show all responses of a webhook in Dialogflow CX

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-cx

I appended different texts in my webhook response, python like:

```
res["fulfillment_response"]["messages"][0]["text"]["text"]
```

so, suppose that the value of the previous code is ["a","b","c"].
This is sent back by webhooks to my Dialogflow CX agent. Why my agent outputs only the first text "a" and not everyone?
Is there a way to retrieve all?

Answer (score 0):

Each item is answered when placed in its own message object within the `message` array. Your webhook response should structure each text item like this:

```py
res["fulfillment_response"]["messages"] = [
    {"text": {"text": ["a"]}},
    {"text": {"text": ["b"]}},
    {"text": {"text": ["c"]}}
]
```